# DevExpress Grid View Error

Tags: aspxgridview

I have a problem using the component GridView of DevExpress on Visual Studio 2010.

What I want to do is really simple. I have a button and when it's clicked, I want to show a message like this: "The column X at row 0 in the gridview has the value Y".

The code of the button is very simple too:

```
Protected Sub b_test_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles b_test.Click
    Dim aux As String
    aux = t_tickets.GetRowValues(0, "numero_de_ticket").ToString

    MsgBox(aux)
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly, BUT it has a strange behaviour.

If I select the first row in the gridview it works fine. But if I select a diferent row, when the button is clicked I get the following error:

```
System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException: A primary key field specified via the KeyFieldName property is not found in the underlying data source. Make sure the field name is spelled correctly
```

I always choose the first row. I dont know why I'm getting this error when I select a different Row.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not the Click function. You are doing a postback that tries to send the selected row to the server side while this row has no keys.

You should check your ASPX file to see the **KeyFieldName** and check that the datasource identification field is what you have declared.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" Id="t_tickets" KeyFieldName="Id">
...
...
...
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I think that you will find that it is erroneous in your case. This means that what you have specified as KeyFieldName is not a Property member of the datasource object that corresponds to the row of your Grid. (Or it is not part of the select statement in the datasource)